# Что не так в этой простой формуле?

Tags: ruby

Ruby меня пинает уже пол дня, а я так и не могу понять, в чем причина. Задача - найти локальный максимум в массиве чисел. Формула ниже. Помогите по-братски.

```
m = [1, 12, 3, 33, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6, 7]

p m.select{ |x| ((m[x] > m[x-1]) && (m[x] > m[x+1])) }
```

Лог ошибок в терминале при вычислении:

```
comparison of Fixnum with Array failed (ArgumentError)

from rub.rb:2:in `block in <main>'
from rub.rb:2:in `select'
from rub.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: 1. `.select` возвращает не индекс, а сам элемент.
2. `[x+1]` вернет массив, конечно, что и вызывает ошибку сравнения массива с числом.

Comment: Тогда как задать предыдущее и последующее число? Я задал это математически

Comment: @bro_one

> Я задал это математически

.

> **не индекс, а сам элемент**

Answer (score 1):

select применяет блок для каждого элемента (у вас это |х|) и возвращает массив значений, для которых результат блока -- истина. В вашем случае в |x| не индекс, а значение.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select

Я бы сделал простым циклом. Но можно и с помощью inject.

Comment: Я так понимаю, данная форма записи подходит только для работы с индексами, но никак не со значениями?

Comment: Вы про какую форму?

Comment: p m.select{ |x| ((m[x] > m[x-1]) && (m[x] > [x+1])) }

Comment: select это такой фильтр для выбора определённых значений массива (грубо говоря). Вы его неправильно применяете и судя по всему не понимаете как он работает.

Comment: Он парсит значения. И если они подходят под условия блока (то бишь true), то он их выдает.

Comment: Для вас проблема в том, что он не сохраняет данные между вычислениями блока.

Comment: Ах вот они в чем тонкости.

Answer (score 0):

Что требуется-то? Числа, их индексы или и то, и другое?

```
(1..m.size-2).map do |i|
  [m[i], i] if m[i] == [m[i-1], m[i], m[i+1]].max
end.compact

=> [[12, 1], [33, 3], [4, 5]]
```